# How a value is passed to the jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding jQuery. I assume that this is some kind of characteristics of javascript as jQuery is a JavaScript library.

Here is my example:

```
$("#globe").load(function(e) { console.log("Globe image has loaded"); });
```

My question is. What is passed to the e parameter and mainly how. As it is not getting the value anywhere. This is an example taken from the tutorial that checks if the image is loaded. But I've seen a lot of this examples and it's frustrating that I don't understand it.

The next example is something like this:

```
$.easing["myfunc"] = function(i) {return i*i}
```

How is the 'i' counting? I assume (again) that it get's a value but from where as it is not initialised anywhere. If you have a time to explain this in simple words please do I'll be grateful or if you could give a link to a tutorial. I have looked in google by such key words like passing values to a function in javascript or something like that but I did not seem to find what I was looking for.

Comment: `e` is the `event` object. If you are having a hard time to understand this, then you should probably step away from jQuery and get more familiar with the native `addEventListener` first.

Comment: Go through docs http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: if i = 3 then i returns 3*3 == 9

Comment: it' not the problem that I don't understand evenets or what they are, the thing that I don't understand is how the function which is assigned "knows" taht it should get the event and not for examle an integer or string or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is passed to the e paramter

See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

`e` (or `eventObject` as the argument is named in the documentation) is an [Event Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

> and mainly how.

You pass a function as an argument when you call a function written by the jQuery developers.

Their code calls your function (later on) with the arguments they say they will call it with.

The same applies with your second example, except that your function is assigned to a property instead of being passed as an argument to a function. They are just two different ways to pass objects around.

---

Essentially it boils down to this:

```
function call_a_function_with_3(a_function) {
  a_function(3);
}  

function alert_the_first_argument(first_argument) {
  alert(first_argument);
}

call_a_function_with_3(alert_the_first_argument);
```

Comment: hmm I don't know if I understand correctly but in my first example something which is the efect of the load (return value) is an event so it is sent to my funtion and no mather what I call the parameter it could be even foo right? And in the second example something from the easing is returning the int value and this is passed to my funtion as an parameter. And again no matther what I call it? That's right? how to I know what is returned by the object from the docs?

Comment: "return value" — Not a return value. A function argument. "is an event" — An event *object*. "That's right?" — Yes, argument names are local to the function. The values assigned to those names are determined by the code that calls the function. "how to I know what is returned by the object from the docs?" — umm, they describe the object, so you just read them.